Disabling upower breaks pm-suspend. How can I suspend my system without upower enabled?
I have done some hardware modifications so my battery always indicates 0%, which is fine for me.
However, system keeps shutting down because of the critical battery level by upower.
I have tried to change the configuration of upower, by setting CriticalPowerAction=Nothing in /etc/UPower/UPower.conf but that doesn't help. So I completely disabled upower by:
sudo systemctl mask upower.service

Now my system keeps working. However, I can't use pm-suspend now, because the system now tries to suspend and immediately wakes up.
How can I use pm-suspend without re-enabling the upower.service?
(Debian, XFCE4, kernel: 5.19)
